# ransack when i am use sort_link ignores search criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ransack

Good Evening.

i have this code, when i am hit  sort link it ignores  search criteria and sends event.all with sort criteria only

i think problem is i am on first load sets some variables  but path and params  are empty

well problem is  on lines wih ends with

> unless params[:q]

Controller

```
def index
   @q = Event.search(params[:q])
   #predefined search items if no search at all  
   @q.datum_eq=Date.current() unless params[:q]
   @q.cil_id_eq=Sklad.first.id unless params[:q]
   @events = @q.result
end
```

view

```
<%= search_form_for @q ,:html => { :class => "form-inline" } do |f| %>
<%= f.search_field :datum_eq, class: 'form-control' %>
<%=f.collection_select :cil_id_eq, Sklad.all, :id, :name,{},{class: "form-control"}%>
<%= sort_link(@q, :dodavatel) %>
end
```

params
when it went properly

```
 <ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"datum_eq"=>"20.04.2017", "cil_id_eq"=>"1"}, "controller"=>"events", "action"=>"index"} permitted: false>
```

improperly params

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"q"=>{"s"=>"dodavatel asc"}, "controller"=>"events", "action"=>"index"} permitted: false>
```

Comment: its totally ignore  settings of  datum_eq

Comment: what do you have in index method `params` ?

Comment: I have tried same configuration and it works fine. Can you show result sql queries from log for that code? Also are you sure `index` method is executing and there are no callbacks around `index` method?

Comment: this controller is root and only one idea which i am thinking on first load he dont have choosed  datum_eq so question is how to redirect when params q not exist

Comment: this problem showed when i am started used  sort_link

Comment: well i think issue is  during first load is sort_links  dont have proper params to read